# Liferay 7 - Wildfly 10 and "X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff"

Tags: javascript, jsp, configuration, liferay, wildfly

I'm struggeling around with Liferay 7 on Wildfly 10 and the according server configuration.

Calling my local installation serves me in the according response the following header:

```
...
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
...
```

Well, I really appreciate this normally, since it is an usefull security option against cross side scripting, but in conjunction with Liferay this causes the following error on the browser console:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/available_languages.jsp?bro…e&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&languageId=de_DE&b=7002&t=1471516992592' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The problem with this error is that this leads to a non-functionality in the cms-backend when you try to configure content or pages. The according menus cannot be opened anymore.

**What happens:** In the above jsp-file there is also javascript contained which will not be execuded because the above header will be respected by the browser and is blocked therefore since the served mime type (text/html) is not valid.

I investigated this problem first in Chrome and since yesterday and after an update also in the new version of Firefox.

I tried to find the according location within the configuration files of Liferay and Wildfly and to disable it, but without any success. No matter what I try the header will still be served by Wildfly.

In addition this header is only served when I open the according web page in Liferay. If I open the management console for Wildfly in the browser the header is not there anymore.

So I pretend its a concrete problem either of my Liferay installation or Liferay itself.  Does anyone know which configuration file I have to adapt in order to disable the serving of this header?

### Update

I think the non working JavaScript is a result because of the browser is blocking the execution of the contained JavaScript.

I opened the backend / control panel and moved to "Content". The error message is still there

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/o/frontend-js-web/liferay/available_languages.jsp?br…e&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&languageId=de_DE&b=7002&t=1471516992592' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

When I click now on an element it gives me the following error

> everything.jsp?browserId=other&themeId=admin_WAR_admintheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifi…:80165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'de_DE' of undefined(…)

So no surprise the first error leads to a following issue in JavaScript since the language object is not set. But this leads to the fact that the according menu will not be opened.

In between I found the according property

...
http.header.secure.x.content.type.options
...
in the "system.properties" file as you described and I set it to "false" in my "portal-ext.properies" file. Afterwards I restarted the server but the header is still there.

Any ideas where I can switch this property off elsewhere? Maybe I should mention that it is only a development environment and later on in the productive environment I have to find another solution for this.

Comment: Update: I created the system-ext.properties file under .../WEB-INF/classes and the reset of the propertie works now. Restarted the server and now its working in Chrome! I can use the backend and the menus are opened as expected. Really strange, looks to me that the source code has to be updated in order to provide a real javascript file instead or you use the option "http.header.secure.x.content.type.options.urls.excludes=" to exclude the according url / path on the server! I think about if I should open a bug at liferay.com. –

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know which configuration file I have to adapt in order to disable the serving of this header.

That is configured in [`system.properties`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/system.properties#L159-L165). You can change it in `system-ext.properties`. If it doesn't exists, just create one next to `portal-ext.properties`.

#### PLEASE NOTE

I don't think this has anything to do with `X-Content-Type-Options` itself. This header was [introduced in Liferay over 3 years ago](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-39202) and by now it's been used in many production environments (including such deployed on WildFly).

If you pay attention to the error message it actually says

> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

So for some reason the response MIME type is `text/html` and not `application/javascript` as expected. From the information you've provided it's impossible to tell why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (with Jboss EAP 7 (~Wildfly 10) and LR 7.0 GA4 CE).
It seems that this is a (recurring?) [bug](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-54266) in LR.
I would not turn off that HTTP header, I think it has the reason why it is there. Instead of that, I applied the suggested patch in the proper bundle and it worked for me (I don't know that this is recommended or not, but it works). 
The bundle that contains the mentioned available_languages.jsp could be found among the OSGI bundles, in case of LR7 here:
$LIFERAY_HOME/osgi/state/org.eclipse.osgi/338/0/bundleFile
This is an OSGI jar, just open it, look for the jsp file in META-INF/resources/liferay folder, open it, put the line

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

among the other directives and put it back to the bundle. 
The jboss after this modification should be stopped, the $LIFERAY_HOME/work folder should be deleted (it may be work without this, I don't know, I did it). and start your jboss again. 
After this step my Liferay instance worked well.

Good luck!

Update:
The solution above just a temporary one, because those folders belongs to the osgi runtime and these bundleFiles will be created only during the liferay's first run - and it seems from time to time liferay update it from the original location that is the lpkg files. So if you would like to solve this problem permanently, fix that jsp in the $LIFERAY_HOME/osgi/marketplace/Liferay CE Foundation.lpkg!com.liferay.frontend.js.web-1.0.41.jar - the bundleFile above will be create from this jar.

Answer (score 0):

in Liferay 7, we may get this error if we are trying to include any .js files in .jsp page.
ex:

```
<script src="/o/module-name/js/jsfile.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

to solve the error, 
go to the bnd.bnd file inside module-name/ and add the following.

```
Web-ContextPath: /module-name
```

It will work.

Thanks